# Reordering a list in python

Tags: python, list, match

Here I need to compare list1 items with list2 items, if a item missed, then I want insert `False` at missed item index of list1.

My input is

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [3,1,4]
```

Excepted output is

```
result = [1, False, 3, 4]
```

I tried this:

```
result = []
for x in list1:
    for i in xrange(0,len(list2)):
        if set(x) == set(list2[i]):
           result.append(x)
```

Comment: What if the lists had duplicates?

Comment: Please do **not** make substantial changes to your question that invalidates its existing answers.

Comment: Consider creating a new question. And in your new question you'll need to explain the relationship between your input lists, as it's currently not clear _why_ you'd expect that output.

Comment: You've edited the question. How is `[1,2]` in `list2`? Or `[2,3]` or any of them for that matter. I think that you need to explain how that works, e.g. do lists need to be flattened, sorted, whatever?

Comment: Dinesh, please stop making major edits to this question. If you asked the wrong question entirely or need to ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button at the top of the page. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [620]: [i if i in list2 else False for i in list1]
Out[620]: [1, False, 3, 4]
```

If you are not familiar with `list comprehensions` you could use solution with loop:

```
result = []
for x in list1:
    if x in list2:
        result.append(x)
    else:
        result.append(False)

print(result)
[1, False, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple to do using an [`if` conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in a [`list` comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries):

```
>>> list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list2 = [3, 1, 4]
>>> res = [i if i in list2 else False for i in list1]
>>> print(res)
[1, False, 3, 4]
```

What this does is it takes every element in the `list1` list and checks if it is `in` the second list `list2`. If so, returns the item `i` itself, if not returns `False`.